# How do I store the sound generated in this pyaudio stream into a WAV or MP3 file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.2, pyaudio

```
"""Play a fixed frequency sound."""
from __future__ import division
import math
from pyaudio import PyAudio

def sine_tone(frequency, duration, volume=1, sample_rate=22050):
    n_samples = int(sample_rate * duration)
    restframes = n_samples % sample_rate

    p = PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(1), # 8bit
                    channels=1, # mono
                    rate=sample_rate,
                    output=True)
    s = lambda t: volume * math.sin(2 * math.pi * frequency * t / sample_rate)
    samples = (int(s(t) * 0x7f + 0x80) for t in range(n_samples))
    for buf in zip(*[samples]*sample_rate): # write several samples at a time
        stream.write(bytes(bytearray(buf)))

    # fill remainder of frameset with silence
    stream.write(b'\x80' * restframes)

    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()


def playScale(scale):
    for x in scale:
        print(x)
        sine_tone(frequency = x,
                  duration = 1,
                  volume=.5,
                  sample_rate = 50000)
```

The playScale function accepts an array of frequencies and plays them using the sine_tone function. How do I save this series of sounds into .WAV file or a .MP3 file?

Answer (score 0):

you should write all the audio data to one stream, then you can save this stream using the 'wave' library in python which is cappable of manipulating wave files.

However, with your current code i'm not sure how it would work as you are writing seperate streams per sound / tone. Might want to pass a stream into that function so you can append too that stream and save with a different function later wwhen all audio is rendered.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html